# Copiando arquivos com mesmo nome para um diretório sem sobrescrever (R!)

Tags: r

Olá, eu estou com um problema.

Eu tenho um diretório fictício que contém um conjunto de pastas, cada pasta dentro de si contém uma pasta de protocolo, e dentro de cada pasta eu tenho um ou mais arquivos. Ex:

```
  Pasta    Protocolo     Arquivo(s)
    A    ->    1     ->     x  
    B    ->    2     ->     y  
    C    ->    1     ->     z , x
```

O meu desafio é transferir as pastas dos protocolos para um novo diretório e colocar os arquivos dentro dessas pastas sem sobrescreve-los. Então o resultado ideal seria:

```
   Protocolo     Arquivo(s)
       1     ->     x (1) , x (2) , z  
       2     ->     y
```

A pasta e o protocolo estão discriminados em um df(test), então eu estou criando esses diretórios com um loop:

```
for (i in 1:3){ 
print(i)
  pasta_to <- paste("F:/", 
                    test$pasta[i], sep="/")

  # Cria o diretório se ele não existe

  ifelse(!dir.exists(pasta_to), 
         dir.create(pasta_to, recursive=TRUE), FALSE)

  pasta_from = paste("C:/Meus Documentos/destino", 
                     test$pasta_origem[i], 
                     test$pasta_do_anexo_resposta[i], 
                     sep="/")  

  files_from <- list.files(pasta_from)
  path_from <- paste(pasta_from, files_from, sep="/")
  file.copy(from=path_from, to = pasta_to, overwrite = F)
  }
```

Com esse código ele acaba sobrescrevendo os arquivos com o mesmo nome x:

```
   Protocolo     Arquivo(s)
       1     ->     x  , z  
       2     ->     y
```

Como eu faço para não sobrescrever os arquivos?

Comment: Uma observação: no caso real, eu não sei o nome dos arquivos, então eu  não poderia usar um ifelse(file.exists())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jéssica, tudo bem?

Não é que o `file.copy()` acaba sobrescrevendo os aquivos com o mesmo nome. Pelo contrário, ele NÃO sobrescreve arquivos com o mesmo nome, já que você setou `overwrite = F`.

Uma possível solução, porém trabalhosa, é criar uma função que compare a lista de arquivos da pasta de origem com a lista de arquivos da pasta de destino. Caso haja aquivos com o mesmo nome, alterar o nome, por exemplo colocar um sufixo para diferenciar. Aí sim, depois disso executar o `file.copy()`.

Vamos para a solução:

```
# Definindo as pastas de origem e destino
path_origem <- "C:/origem"
path_destino <- "C:/destino"

# Função que verifica se existe algum arquivo com o mesmo nome entre as duas listas
verifica.repetido <- function(origem, destino) {
  if(length(setdiff(lista_origem, lista_destino)) != length(origem)) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}

# Função que adiciona "#" no nome do arquivo de origem, para diferenciar do de destino
renomeia <- function(origem, destino, path_origem) {
  for (i in 1:length(origem)) {
    for (j in 1:length(destino)) {
      if (origem[i] == destino[j]) {
        novo_nome = gsub("\\.", "#.", origem[i])
        file.rename(from = paste(path_origem, origem[i], sep = "/"),
                    to = paste(path_origem, novo_nome, sep = "/"))
      }
    }
  }
  return(origem)
}

# Obtendo a lista de arquivos das pastas de origem e destino
lista_origem <- list.files(path_origem)
lista_destino <- list.files(path_destino)

# Verificando se há algum nome repetido entre as listas
repetido <- verifica.repetido(lista_origem, lista_destino)

# Se houver repetido, o laço abaixo executa até que não haja mais nenhum repetido
repeat{
  renomeia(lista_origem, lista_destino, path_origem)
  lista_origem <- list.files(path_origem)
  repetido <- verifica.repetido(lista_origem, lista_destino)
  if(!repetido) {
      break
    }
}

# Incluindo o caminho completo da pasta de origem
lista_origem <- list.files(path_origem, full.names = T)

# Colando os arquivos de origem na pasta de destino
file.copy(from = lista_origem, to = path_destino)
```

Tenho certeza que existe uma forma menos trabalhosa, mas de qualquer forma, desta maneira é possível colar quantas vezes for necessário, na pasta de destino, arquivos com nomes já existentes. A única coisa que vai acontecer á a adição do caracter # no final do arquivo.